# Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro touch screen not working anymore

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, lenovo-laptop

I ran a bunch installers today trying to fix the Bluetooth, and now the screen touch gestures does not work anymore.

Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro drivers are here:

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS038317

Does anybody knows which one installs the touch screen driver?

UPDATE: And the final Bluetooth driver that I installed was this:

[Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software for Bluetooth® technology for Windows 8.1](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23761&keyword=bluetooth&lang=eng)

Not sure if this could be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried updating your screen drivers via Windows Update? Also, I think the driver you're looking for is the `Lenovo Motion Control` driver, under the `Software and Utility` category.

Comment: Windows Update or Device Manager? If device manager, under what category can I find the screen? Monitors, display adpaters, etc.?

Comment: Both are common locations, look for any possible hardware under those categories and update the drivers. And you can run both, but sometimes the device manager doesn't connect to windows update to install drivers unless the search fails. You can run windows update and look for the optional updates or even the important updates section to see if there are drivers available for your screen (and maybe other hw too). You may want to check the *offer recommended updates…* option for windows update on its control panel page.